# How to make the same program act like a server and client (using sockets in java)

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

How can I send and receive from the same program in java ? To make matters worse, I need to do both in the same time in parallel.

Comment: The tags you use indicate that you understand you'll need to use multiple threads; beyond that, no special tricks. Do you have a specific problem you need help with?

Comment: yes, is putting the sending and receiving part in separate threads (and further making the serving part multithreaded for capability to serve multiple clients) work? is this the *normal* way to handle a situation like this ?

Comment: @return0 Please do not forget that in JVM, uninterrupted thread lifecycle is never guaranteed. They always have the probability of being suspended, de-prioritized, resumed, etc. This will break some stuff at some point.

Comment: @CengizCan So, then what would you suggest I look into ?

Comment: just make sure u dont use the same resources without protecting them in different threads, and that different threads dont count on an action being made by another thread without chking that the other thread was really done. u'll be ok

Comment: @return0 Yes, that's the normal way to do things. One thread calls `accept()` in a loop on a `ServerSocket`; whenever `accept()` returns a new connection, you can create another thread to service that client, and then loop back to calling `accept()` again. When the program is acting as a client, you might simply do that in the main thread, not creating a dedicated thread -- unless the program has to simultaneously act as a client multiple times. Do be careful of shared data between threads (i.e., use locks judiciously), and don't worry about whatever it is CengizCan is trying to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a well behaved queue such as a `BlockingQueue` between two `Thread`s.

```
public class TwoThreads {
  static final String FINISHED = "Finished";
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // The queue
    final BlockingQueue<String> q = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(10);
    // The sending thread.
    new Thread() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        String message = "Now is the time for all good men to come to he aid of the party.";
        try {
          // Send each word.
          for (String word : message.split(" ")) {
            q.put(word);
          }
          // Then the terminator.
          q.put(FINISHED);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
      }
      { start();}
    };
    // The receiving thread.
    new Thread() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          String word;
          // Read each word until finished is detected.
          while ((word = q.take()) != FINISHED) {
            System.out.println(word);
          }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
      }
      { start();}
    };
  }
}
```